# Octave. Get the first element from array

Tags: octave

I have a matrix that looks like:

```
 matrix = 
 106168   1457100277117478     
 106069   1457100277417227    
 111159   1457100277850577   
 24408    1457100278150562
```

I need to take the first element of the second column for my further calculation. But I failed to do that!

The piece of code for that is the following:

```
 time = matrix(:, 2(1));
 format long;
 disp('!time = '); disp(time);
```

As a result I got:

```
!time = 
   1457100277117478
   1457100277417227
   1457100277850577
   1457100278150562
```

I didn't use any loop :( 
I would like to get only the first value, i.e., `1457100277117478`.
What did I do in a wrong way?

Comment: `time = matrix(:, 2(1));` selects the entire second column. I suggest reading the [documentation for indexing](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Index-Expressions.html)

Comment: @ excaza  thank you for reply. For sure I read it. But I can't apply it to my task :(
So these two strings will be the same:
`matrix(:, 2(1))
 matrix(:, 2)`

Comment: Yes, they will. If you want the first value don't use the colon, use `1`...

Comment: oh... I see... The right answer is:
`matrix(1,2);`